# Accessing objects from arraylist

Tags: java, object, arraylist

I am trying to make this program that creates a queue for people, my problem is I cannot seem to get any way to access one of the objects value from within the main class... Any help would be appreciated, I don't think i have a strong understanding on how exactly these access each other.

Here is my code (I have // comment blocks on my attempted accessing code)

```
    import java.util.*;
class Student{
    private int age;
    private String fname;
    private double grade;
    public Student(String fname, int age, double grade) {
        super();
        this.age = age;
        this.fname = fname;
        this.grade = grade;
    }
    public int getAge() {
        return age;
    }
    public String getFname() {
        return fname;
    }
    public double getGrade() {
        return grade;
    }
}


public class javasort
{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        List<Student> studentList = new ArrayList<Student>();
        int end = 0;
        while(end==0){
            String line = in.nextLine();
            if (line.equalsIgnoreCase("end")) {
                end++;
                break;
            }
            String[] studentValues = line.split(" ");
            int[] values = new int[2];
            String fname = studentValues[0];
            for(int i = fname.length(); i < studentValues.length-1; i++){
                values[i] = Integer.parseInt(studentValues[i]);
            }
            int age = values[0];
            double grade = values[1];
            Student st = new Student(fname, age, grade);
            studentList.add(st);

            // This line wont access anything, I want to be able to get the age of the 2nd last person in line
            // and then compare it to the last person in line. although I cannot seem to be able to "get" the age of the 2nd last.
            Student second = (studentList).getAge(studentList.size()-2);
        }




        for(Student st: studentList){
            System.out.println(st.getFname());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you add some sample input?

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
studentList.get(studentList.size()-2).getAge();
```

what happen if size of list is 1 it will return exception

**Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -1**

Comment: Thank you that works! I know, the parameters of this program is always correct input so I do not have to worry about being outofbounds, I am also going to add an excape if array is empty before all of this.

Comment: Continueing on, I am having a struggle to swap positions with last element and 2nd last one, hinging on the conditions of age and grade.

Answer (score 0):

jj mackubin,

Noticed two points:
1. for loop logic is wrong. Loop is initialized with i=fname.length(), let just say you enter name with 5 letters then loop with start with 5 rather then starting from 1. 
Initialization condition should be i=1 as per your code which reads name at 0th index.
2. Use get(int index) function as suggested by @Prabhakar Kumar to get the Student object and then corresponding attribute of the class.

Comment: I believe my loop logic is odd, but works. I have a substring to pull out the String that goes to the first space. After that the loop is meant to pull the int and double out of it. input would be something like "Name 80 80".